# Python to C# can't understand requests.put(url,data=...)

Tags: python, c#, httpwebrequest

I can't figure out the image data send error, not familiar with JSON.

Given this working Python code:

```
def uploadImage(image_name, folder_path, location):
    path = folder_path + '\\' + image_name
    with open(path, "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())     
    req_body = {"filename": image_name, "location": location}    
    resp_post = requests.post( "myURL", json=req_body)
    if resp_post.status_code == 200:        
        url = resp_post_json = resp_post.json()['url'] # facing c# problem here       
        resp_put = requests.put(url,data=encoded_string)           
        if resp_put.status_code != 200:
            return "PUT request error : {}".format(resp_put.reason)
    else:
        retur
```

> "POST request error : {}".format(resp_post.reason)

C# code:

```
internal void UploadImage(string strImagePathNName, string strImageName, string strLoaction)
 {
      try
      {
          // read file in base 64 string
          string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(strImagePathNName));
          if (base64String.Length > 0)
          {
              var webAddr = "myURL";                    
              string json = "{\"filename\":\"" + strImageName + "\"," + "\"location\":\"" + strLoaction + "\"}";                    
              HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);                    
              httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";                    
              httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

              using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
              {
                  streamWriter.Write(json);
                  streamWriter.Close();
              }

              bool bIsGotResponseFromServer = false;
              var strResponseUri = string.Empty;

              using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
              {
                  if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                  {
                      using (Stream respStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                      {
                          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                          strResponseUri = reader.ReadToEnd();                                
                          UrlFromJson myojb = (UrlFromJson)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponseUri, typeof(UrlFromJson));
                          strResponseUri = myojb.url; //retrieved the URl
                          bIsGotResponseFromServer = true;
                      }
                  }
              }

              if (bIsGotResponseFromServer)
              {
                  httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strResponseUri);                       
                  httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                  httpWebRequest.Method = "post";                                
                  json = "{\"data\":\"" + base64String + "\"}";

                  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) 
                  {
                      streamWriter.Write(json); /// not sure about this line                           
                      streamWriter.Close();
                  }

                  using (HttpWebResponse webResponse1 = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse()) // received error here
                  {
                      if (webResponse1.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                      {
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      catch (WebException e)
      {                
      }
  }
```

Comment: When writing a question use the Text Editor toolbar buttons - format code and format quotes. Good luck!

Comment: put it as an answer - its encouraged to be able to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Just using the base64 string instead of the *httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream*:

```
Stream.Write(base64String,0, base64String.Length);
```

and set:

```
httpWebRequest.Method = "PUT";
```